# audio recorder blackberry error

Tags: audio, blackberry, recorder

I am developing an app for sending audio .amr files to the server. But the server is giving me the following message:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html> 
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://airtelforum.com/main?InterceptSource=0&ClientLocation=in&ParticipantID=kk6rp2jf3dkl4v52nla5u7676ej8r6uf&FailureMode=1&SearchQuery=&FailedURI=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myserver.com%2Fbb%2Fupload3.php%3Fim%3D123456783648138&AddInType=4&Version=2.1.8-1.90base&Referer=&Implementation=0"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   url="http://airtelforum.com/main?InterceptSource=0&ClientLocation=in&ParticipantID=kk6rp2jf3dkl4v52nla5u7676ej8r6uf&FailureMode=1&SearchQuery=&FailedURI=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myserver.com%2Fbb%2Fupload3.php%3Fim%3D123456783648138&AddInType=4&Version=2.1.8-1.90base&Referer=&Implementation=0";
   if(top.location!=location){
    var w=window,d=document,e=d.documentElement,b=d.body,x=w.innerWidth||e.clientWidth||b.clientWidth,y=w.innerHeight||e.clientHeight||b.clientHeight;url+="&w="+x+"&h="+y;
   }
   window.location.replace(url);   
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Can anybody figure out what the problem is? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the php i'm using is working with other uploading files.

Comment: u sending it as audio data ?

Comment: yes, i'm uploading .amr files

Comment: sorry to keep you waiting. My eclipse crashed. I tested it now but its giving null response..i'm testing this in my simulator..